# getting the id of current subcategory in magento

Tags: php, magento

I know we can get the id of the current/active categories in Magento. I have products in different subcategories and I'd like to display these products as related products. My question is, is it possible to get the id of the currently selected subcategory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch current category children if any if you are on product list or product details page.

```
$_currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ;
$_currentCategories->getChildrenCategories() will give you all children category.
```

You can then filter your product collection based on category.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(cat_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

This will give you product collection of your subcategories